# How to ensure all views on App object get defined before loading

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app that uses a global App namespace like this

```
var App = App || {};
App.Config = {};
App.Models = {};
App.Views = {};
App.Collections = {};
```

In the file `/views/myappviews.js`, I have twelve different views defined on that `App.Views` namespace, such as

```
  App.Views.BlahBlahView = Backbone.View.extend({
  });
```

If I inspect the App  object in the console in the route where the application runs , it shows each of the twelve different views defined on the App.object. However, in the test part of my application at `test.html`, I require all of the application files like

```
  <script src="../app/views/myappviews.js"></script>
```

and when I inspect the App object in the console, it only shows the first three views defined in that file like this

```
    Object
         Views
             HomeView
             BlahBlahView
             FooView
```

so when I try to test any of the other 9 views defined later in the file, it says they are undefined, even though I put the script tags for that file above the actual test specs. (As far as the models go, however, all the 8 or 9 models that are defined in `../app/models/mymodels.js` are visible on the `App` object in the test route).

Why would only some of the views defined on the App object in that file be visible and how could I arrange it so that they are all visible in the test area of the application?

Comment: probably typo in question only, but `src=".../app` has a dot too many for my liking

Comment: yes that's just a typo, thanks. that's not how it is in my application, or nothing would load

Comment: Did you consider including the usage of requirejs (http://requirejs.org/) library? It really helps on handling dependencies.

Comment: Or you can make use of define js(http://fixjs.github.io/define.js/) as well. We use requireJS to load the module first and then define([""], function("") {}  for loading necessary views/layouts etc.

Comment: I didn't think this would be an issue where require.js is needed. If the file containing the views is available before the file with the specs is declared, and some of the views in that file are getting defined, then why not all of them